# How can I get only the group a computer is in from Get-ADComputer?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to read from a csv formatted: computername,group.

I need to get the group a computer is in and delete it from that group, and add it to another group. Right now, I'm just worried about getting the current group so I can delete it from. I'm using this, but I can't seem to drill down further:

```
Get-ADComputer name -Properties MemberOf | where {$_.MemberOf -like "*UPDATE*"}
```

This returns the usual information, DN, Enabled, DNSHostName, ObjectClass, etc. How can I grab just the group to store it in a variable?

Comment: you can use 'Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement' CmdLets http://ss64.com/ps/quest.html, the Quest return many other properties and work on old AD scheme

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
Get-ADComputer name -Properties MemberOf | where {$_.MemberOf -like "*UPDATE*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf
```

That should take just the property you want (`MemberOf`) and give you the value only (that's what `-ExpandProperty` does).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this narrows it down, but It still is displaying multiple CNs. I'm interested in the CN with Update in the name

Comment: Hey. It looks to me like you select and where pipes are reversed. Should be select then where. I would think this returns everything as long as there is one match. It should be this `| select -expand memberof| where{$_ -like "*update*"}`